# postgresql bgworker SIGTERM handler called twice

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

Im using postgresql 10.1 on Mac.

I have a trouble in terminating a background worker using SIGTERM. In my project, im creating a new background worker using **RegisterBackgroundWorker()**. i have included a test_function, as a signal handler for SIGTERM. No other signal handlers are defined.

```
pqsignal(SIGTERM, test_function)
```

when i issue `pkill -15 postgres`, i see that the handler is being called twice. Why does it happen? Am i missing anything??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `pkill` sends the signal to all processes that match the given name, and Postgres is multi-threaded.

Use regular `kill` with the process ID of the background process that you wish to nuke.

Comment: I had to give `kill <postmaster-pid>` which issued SIGTERM to the bgworker once. Thanks :)